# Прервать цикл forEach (javascript)

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
massiv.forEach(function(item, i) {
  if (item == "1") {
    console.log(i);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Есть массив со значениями.

Внутри цикла есть условие поиска значения массива.

Задача: остановить дальнейший перебор цикла при первом найденном значении.

Спасибо за помощь.

Решение:
(спасибо Lieutenant Jim Dangle)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3].some(function(el,i) {

         if (el == 3) {  
         console.log(i);
         return el;
         }

    });
```

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle, твой код так же не работает как и код в вопросе  :-)

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle, это просто убирает синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: Добавь в вопрос пример твоего массива, и что именно в нем ты хочешь найти и вывести.

Comment: Код решения неверен. результат возвращаемый функцией Callback переданной в `some` нужен только для проверки останавливать ли проход по коллекции или нет. Поэтому если вдруг искомый элемент будет `0` - то в твоем случае some пройдет по всей коллекции

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[метод forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) не предусматривает возможности прервать обход коллекции.

Если нужно проверить наличие конкретного элемента удовлетворяющего условию, лучше использовать [метод some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var massiv = ['2', '1', '3'];

console.log(massiv.some(function(item) {
  console.log('some', item);
  return (item == "1");
}));
```

Если проверяются полностью объекты, можно использовать [метод indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var massiv = ['2', '1', '3'];

console.log(massiv.indexOf("1"));
```

Если нужно найти индекс элемента удовлетворяющего условию, то подойдет [метод findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
var massiv = ['2', '1', '3'];

console.log(massiv.findIndex(function(item) {
  console.log('findIndex', item);
  return item == "1";
}));
```

---

Если очень хочется использовать именно `forEach` - можно поместить его в [try..catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) и кидать ошибку если элемент найден.

```js
var massiv = ['2', '1', '3'];
try {
  massiv.forEach(function(item, i) {
    console.log('foreach', i);
    if (item == "1") {
      throw {
        reason: "finded",
        index: i
      }
    }
  });
} catch ({
  reason, index
}) {
  if (reason) {
    console.log(reason, ':', index)
  }
}
```

---

Вместо встроенных функций массива, можно также воспользоваться циклом [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). В этом случае для прерывания цикла можно использовать [выражение break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

Comment: Во всех варианта у Вас именно поиск конкретного элемента. А задача была найти первый найденный. В Вашей интерпритации массива было бы так: var massiv = ['2', '1', '3', '1']; И нужно найти индекс первой найденной еденички (то есть результатом остановки было бы значение 1 (второй элемент массива)

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии, все методы `some`, `findIndex` - прекращают выполнение, как только callback вернет `true`. Метод `indexOf`, находит первое вхождение элемента. начиная с указанного индекса, так как индекс не указан, проверка начинается с первого элемента массива.

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии, если задача заключается просто в проверке наличия элементов в массиве. то foreach вообще не нужен. В противном случае, все методы делают то же самое что и код в вопросе, за исключением прекращения выполнения когда условие выполнилось

Answer (score 4):

В методе `forEach` не предусмотренa остановка как в лупе посредством брейк.

Использовать `every` заместо `forEach`. Когда будет `false`, все остановится.

Это самый правильный способ.

```
massiv.every(function(item, i) {
  if (item == "1") {
    console.log(i);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: на счет _Это самый правильный способ_ - можно поспорить

Comment: я привел пример точно на поставленый вопрос, 
это делает то, что надо @Менеджер Типографии, все остальные ответы, по моему мнению не еффктивны.
есть четко поставленый вопрос, и есть решение...

Comment: some - делает абсолютно то же самое. разница только в знаке сравнения. И все это менее эффективно чем обычный `for` за счет постоянного вызова функции-коллбэка. Кроме того, неизвестно что вообще нужно автору, что именно он хочет делать с полученным элементом. нужен ли ему элемент или индекс элемента и т.д.

Comment: тут можно долго спорить

Comment: О чем я и написал в своем первом комментарии :)

Comment: :).активно закидали ответами - актуальная тема :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
[1, 2, 3].some(function(el) {
  console.log(el);
  return el === 2;
});
```

Comment: Всё гуд, только немного доработал код (в первом сообщении)

Answer (score 0):

Mожно остановить `loop` посредством вызова несуществующей функции и перехвата ошибки:

```js
var massiv = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

try {
  massiv.forEach(function(item, i, vvv) {
    console.log(item);
    if (item == "5") {
      vvv();
    }
  });
} catch (e) {}
```

Comment: стоит добавить пояснение что происходит

Comment: Вместо вызова несуществующей функции стоило бы использовать инструкцию throw.